# Capacitor Camera on Android - How to change Background Color

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, capacitor

I am trying to figure out how to change the background color of this screen when using Capacitor Camera on Android. I'm having a tough time finding docs on this.

[image]

Launching camera from Android using Capacitor gives a background with color I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Capacitor camera plugin it does not directly support the ability to customize the background color. You can set the **background color** for the activity where the camera is located.